# Export SSRS Subscription to Multiple File Share Locations

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel, data-driven

Is it possible to export an SSRS report to multiple paths through a data-driven subscription? Is there a specific delimiter (such as ";") between path names that will allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but if you're using a data driven subscription you can make a table (or #TEMP Table) of your paths and join that to your query.

Instead of one record, you would get as many as there are PATHS you need.

Then use the PATH field for the PATH in the subscription.

[image]

Unfortunately, my current job doesn't have the **Enterprise Edition** with data driven subscriptions so I can't give step-by-step help. Here's a link to help if you need more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187066.aspx